# How to strip special characters out of string?

Tags: regex, string, swift, nsstring, nscharacterset

I have a set with the characters I allow in my string:

```
var characterSet:NSCharacterSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
```

I want to strip *any other* characters from a string so two unformatted data can be considered equal, like this:

```
"American Samoa".lowercaseString == "american_samoa1".lowercaseString
```

the lowercase version of these transformed strings would be `"americansamoa"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's write a function for that (in swift 1.2).

```
func stripOutUnwantedCharactersFromText(text: String, set characterSet: Set<Character>) -> String {
    return String(filter(text) { set.contains($0) })
}
```

You can call it like that:

```
let text = "American Samoa"
let chars = Set("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
let strippedText = stripOutUnwantedCharactersFromText(text, set: chars)
```

Pure swift. Yeah.

Comment: awesome. one comment. You have 2 K's in the Set of characters.

Answer (score 3):

You were on the right track. But you can use the [`invertedSet`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSCharacterSet/invertedSet) on your NSCharSet. That means you **allow** every character you set in your `NSCharSet`, because it's easier to do that way. Otherwise you'd need to check every char you don't want to allow which are many more than set the allowed ones:

```
var charSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ").invertedSet
var unformatted = "american_samoa1"
var cleanedString = join("", unformatted.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(charSet))

println(cleanedString) // "americansamoa"
```

As you see, I use the `join` method on the created array. I do that because you really want a string and otherwise you'd have a array of strings.

Answer (score 3):

Updated the below example for Swift 2.3 to replace the `join` method.

```
let charSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ").invertedSet
let unformatted = "american_samoa1"
let cleanedString = unformatted.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(charSet)).joinWithSeparator("")

print(cleanedString) // "americansamoa"
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3** upgraded answer:

```
let jpegName = "<Hit'n'roll>.jpg"
let disallowedChars = CharacterSet.urlPathAllowed.inverted
let fileName = fileName.components(separatedBy: disallowedChars).joined(separator: "_")
```

Answer (score 2):

This currently works for swift 3.X

```
func strip(unformatted: String) -> String {
    let disallowedChars = CharacterSet.letters.inverted
    let formatted = unformatted.components(separatedBy: disallowedChars).joined(separator: "")
    return formatted.lowercased()
}
```