# How to remove special characters from string in Swift 2?

Tags: ios, string, swift

The answer in
[How to strip special characters out of string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28819779/how-to-strip-special-characters-out-of-string) 
is not working.

Here is what I got and it gives me an error

```
func removeSpecialCharsFromString(str: String) -> String {
    let chars: Set<String> = Set(arrayLiteral: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890+-*=(),.:!_")

    return String(str.characters.filter { chars.contains($0) }) //error here at $0
}
```

The error at `$0` says

> _Element (aka Character) cannot be converted to expected argument type 'String'.

Comment: The line `let text = str` is just silly.

Comment: In your linked question, the operation is performed on `filter(text)` while you are doing it on `text.characters` which is an array, and String has no initializer using the array of characters and hence your function fails.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Like this:

```
func removeSpecialCharsFromString(text: String) -> String {
    let okayChars : Set<Character> = 
        Set("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890+-*=(),.:!_".characters)
    return String(text.characters.filter {okayChars.contains($0) })
}
```

And here's how to test:

```
let s = removeSpecialCharsFromString("père") // "pre"
```

Comment: @Kametrixom Agreed; my goal was to fix the OP's syntax, not to solve the actual problem optimally.

Comment: @Kametrixom Changed it to use set instead of array. Lookup in a set should be much more efficient.

Comment: @durul-dalkanat Historical answer. Swift 2! If you want to give a Swift 4 answer, give it; don't change mine. Thanks.

Answer (score 52):

**SWIFT 4:**

```
func removeSpecialCharsFromString(text: String) -> String {
    let okayChars = Set("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890+-=().!_")
    return text.filter {okayChars.contains($0) }
}
```

More cleaner way:

```
extension String {

    var stripped: String {
        let okayChars = Set("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890+-=().!_")
        return self.filter {okayChars.contains($0) }
    }
}
```

Use this extension like:

```
let myCleanString = "some.Text@#$".stripped
```

Output: "some.Text"

Answer (score 27):

I think that a cleaner solution could be this approach:

```
extension String {
    var alphanumeric: String {
        return self.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.alphanumerics.inverted).joined().lowercased()
    }
}
```

Comment: The only problem with this solution that it'll also remove space between words...

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
someString.removeAll(where: {$0.isPunctuation})
```

Comment: When answering, it's much more helpful to the OP, and any others searching for similar solutions in the future, if you provide some explanation why this is the appropriate solution and how it works.

Answer (score 8):

In **Swift 1.2,**

```
let chars = Set("abcde...")
```

created a set containing all characters from the given string.
In **Swift 2.0** this has to be done as

```
let chars = Set("abcde...".characters)
```

The reason is that a string itself does no longer conform to
`SequenceType`, you have to use the `characters` view explicitly.

With that change, your method compiles and works as expected:

```
func removeSpecialCharsFromString(str: String) -> String {
    let chars = Set("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890+-*=(),.:!_".characters)
    return String(str.characters.filter { chars.contains($0) })
}

let cleaned = removeSpecialCharsFromString("ab€xy")
print(cleaned) // abxy
```

*Remark:* @Kametrixom suggested to create the set only once. So *if* there is 
performance issue with the above method you can either move the
declaration of the set outside of the function, or make it a 
local `static`:

```
func removeSpecialCharsFromString(str: String) -> String {
    struct Constants {
        static let validChars = Set("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890+-*=(),.:!_".characters)
    }
    return String(str.characters.filter { Constants.validChars.contains($0) })
}
```

Comment: I suggest moving the declaration of `chars` outside of the function, as it may be created every time the function is invoked

Answer (score 0):

without removing spaces between words

```
extension String {
    var removeSpecialCharacters: String {
        return self.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.alphanumerics.inverted).filter({ !$0.isEmpty }).joined(separator: " ")
    }
}
```