# Escaping a single quote in swift

Tags: swift, escaping, character

I've used this question

[How to remove special characters from string in Swift 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32851720/how-to-remove-special-characters-from-string-in-swift-2)

Which designates which characters to keep in a string, then removes all other characters.  The function works great.  The line

```
Set("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890+-*=(),.:!_".characters)
```

determines what characters to keep. However, when I try to add in the single quote character ('), single quotes are not kept.  I tried escaping the single quote with \' and putting it in regularly, but to no avail. I don't believe single quotes need to be escaped in Swift.

Would someone care to enlighten me on this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: I tried adding the single quote to the `Set` in the example you linked and it worked properly. Would you mind adding a full code sample of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind! As it turns out, I was calling the removeSpecialCharsFromString function inside a do-catch. Once I moved it outside of the do-clause, everything worked.