# Swift Checking if entire word is present in a string

Tags: ios, string, swift

What I want to do is to check if an entire word is present in a string. Let me give you an example.

```
let mainString = "this is a my string"
let searchString = "str"
if mainString.containsString(searchString) {

}
```

Here this condition will be true but I do not want this. I want it to be true when either "this" or "is" or "a" or "my" or "string" is searched in the mainString meaning I want to compare the whole word not the characters within the string. I hope I have elaborated it.

Answer (score 2):

// The following method will return a string without punctuation and non-required stuff characters

Source of information : [How to remove special characters from string in Swift 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32851720/how-to-remove-special-characters-from-string-in-swift-2)

```
 func removeSpecialCharsFromString(mainString) -> String {
    let okayChars : Set<Character> = 
        Set("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".characters)
    return String(text.characters.filter {okayChars.contains($0) })
} 



let stringWithoutSpecialChars = removeSpecialCharsFromString(mainString)
```

// Source of info : Chris's answer on this page

```
let components = stringWithoutSpecialChars.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
for component in components {
    print(component)
}
```

[image]

Comment: It won't works if the sentence ends by "str" or if there is a ponctuation sign after "str".

Comment: @Maxime try this, maybe if will work.

Comment: @Maxime, I tested. This is working fine.

Comment: *Remark:* a-z are not the only letters used in the world. German has äöü, french has éàû, greek has αβγ, just to note a few :)

Comment: I agree @MartinR. But, at the same time, the Set of characters provides us a flexible way to add them easily.

Comment: I would recommend using NSCharacterSets. Martin's comment regarding foreign characters can be more easily handled by creating an inverse set from the characters you want to exclude, for example, Filtering `NSCharacterSet.punctuationCharacterSet().invertedSet` may work effectively to remove punctuation. I won't update my answer to include anything regarding filtering of works, as it's not indicated as significant within the scope of the original question.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a Regex like that :

```
NSString *pattern = @"\\str\\b";
NSRange range = [text rangeOfString:pattern options:NSRegularExpressionSearch|NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
```

The \b at the end of the pattern do what you want, it will match only whole words.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend splitting your string into components and seeing if a component matches your string. Below is a method that uses components to check if any word matches a given search term.

```
func isTermInString(term:String, stringToSearch:String) -> Bool {
    let components = stringToSearch.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")

    for component in components {
        if component == term {
            return true
        }
    }

    return false
}
```

Comment: what if the sentence is "this is str!". then you would get "this", "is" "str!". Wont work in that case

Comment: Correct, `str` isn't the same word as `str!`, as `!` is a character, much like any other letter.

If that was a significant requirement for the search, you could remove non-alphanumeric characters using a method similar to the question in this link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713918/replace-multiple-characters-in-a-string-in-objective-c