# String with only "0123456789."

Tags: ios, swift, replace

I want to remove every char that is not in this list: "0123456790." from a string

I tried:

```
let characters = NSCharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789.").inverted
string = string.replacingOccurrences(of: characters.allCharacters().description, with: "", options: .regularExpression)

extension CharacterSet {
    func allCharacters() -> [Character] {
        var result: [Character] = []
        for plane: UInt8 in 0...16 where self.hasMember(inPlane: plane) {
            for unicode in UInt32(plane) << 16 ..< UInt32(plane + 1) << 16 {
                if let uniChar = UnicodeScalar(unicode), self.contains(uniChar) {
                    result.append(Character(uniChar))
                }
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove special characters from string in Swift 2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32851720/how-to-remove-special-characters-from-string-in-swift-2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Swift 3**

```
string = (string.components(separatedBy: NSCharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789.").inverted) as NSArray).componentsJoined(by: "")
```

Answer (score 2):

Using part of your code:

```
let charactersSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789.").inverted

extension String {
    func allCharacters() -> String {
        return self.components(separatedBy: charactersSet).joined()
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is slick, but I wonder how well it performs? Unless the compiler optimizes it, it will create a separate String object for every run of digits, requiring multiple memory allocations.  Wouldn't it be faster to iterate through the source string, picking out the digits and appending them to an output string? (Since memory allocations are quite expensive)

Comment: You are correct, in a way, the way that you're proposing is almost as bad as this since swift creates a new string every time that you append. Anyways, I wouldn't take the time to optimize this unless it's necessary.

Comment: It doesnt work for swift3, so I cant test if it is right.

Comment: It works with swift 3, however, strings have a property called characters, so it wasn't working. Try now. @Marckaraujo

Answer (score 1):

Use this extension.

```
extension String {
    var digits: String {
    return components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted)
        .joined(separator: "")
    }
}

let test = "Hello 54-Today is 112216"
let fixed = test.digits
print(fixed) //54112216
```

Comment: That is not correct, as the decimal digits set does not contain the "." character

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
var newString = (origString.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted) as NSArray).componentsJoined(byString: "").replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: "", options: .literal, range: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

In you could alter your first regex to include a space after the 9:

In swift:

```
var str = "test Test 333 9599 999";
val strippedStr = str.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("[^0-9 ]",   withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.RegularExpressionSearch, range:nil);
// strippedStr = " 33 9599 999"
```

While this leaves the leading space, you could apply a whitespace trimming to deal with that:

```
strippedStr.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet())
// strippedStr = "33 9599 999"
```